# Can Alamofire taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection wait for request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, urlsession

```
delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { session, task, response, request in
    var finalRequest = request
    if let originalRequest = task.originalRequest, let urlString = originalRequest.url{
        finalRequest = originalRequest
    }
    let parameters = [
        "X-CSRF-Token": "unsafe",
        "xs-username": UserDefaultService().username,
        "xs-password": UserDefaultService().password
    ]
    self.isRefreshing = true
    manager.request(APIPath.login.path, method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                break
        }
    }
    return finalRequest
}
```

I am using `taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection` to handle `HTTP` request redirection by `Alamofire`.

When the redirection is triggered, it will refresh login token then use original request again.

But the problem is that final request will not wait for completion of refreshing.

So the server will still redirect new requests and `delegate` will be triggered so many time before refreshing complete.

How do I make return wait for completionHandler? Is there a better solution for this case?

Comment: you are using return, but you need to use a closure instead, this is an async  call

Comment: That is how Async behaves. it will not wait for you. You can show loading in screen while sending request and hide it when it finishes.

Comment: can you post your full method code?